# Spotify - Waiting animation stutters

Tags: javascript, gif, spotify

I'm currently trying to get a  smooth waiting animation in my spotify app. But my gif just stops after one iteration (but in my chrome it doesn't) and animating it with a javascript timer is everything but smooth.

How can i fix that?

Comment: Could you post your gif image?

Comment: I created it on http://ajaxload.info/